# How can I use style tag in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

So I'm in a situation where I have to use `<style>` tag, That is because I have multiple pages (I'm using react router DOM) so I cant apply the same style to every page as that would mess things up. Is there a way I can use `<style>` tag in JSX?

I have to use style tag like this:

```
function RandomScreen(){
    return (
        <div>
          <style></style>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply import a stylesheet into your page:

```
import './main.css'
```

Another solution is to use Emotion and the Global component:
https://emotion.sh/docs/globals

Comment: How can I link CSS with the component?

Comment: You can specify the className prop and use the classes defined in the CSS file.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use separate css file for every component and import every css file in every component you need.

```
import './RandomScreen.css';
```

Comment: How can I link CSS with the component?

Comment: You can scope it to a single component but you can add different class names or ID to the component in that file. It's for easier organization of css but you still need to take care of classNames and selectors like it's global css

Comment: if you have css file in same folder as component, on top of component add import './fileName.css';